# How to group by two columns? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

---

The code that I posted below is the API request from which I make a table. This table has 4 columns: id, userid, title. I want to understand how I can sort by userid and title, as shown in the photo. It would be great if the steps were described in detail.

---

1. I'm trying to group the tab as shown [in the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl6Ew.png), but I can't.
   Can you suggest/show me how to do this?

---

2. Also wanted to know how to reset the group value of a column?

---

I will be grateful for any help.

---

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./GroupByUserID.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class GroupByUserID extends React.Component {
  // Constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.apiFetch();
  };

  //Fetch data from API
  apiFetch = () => {
    return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return { ...prevState, items: json };
        });
      });
  };

  // Sort UserID
  setSortedItemsUserID = () => {
    const { items } = this.state;
    const sortedUserID = items.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.userId < b.userId) {
        return items.direction === "ascending" ? -1 : 1;
      }
      if (a.userId > b.userId) {
        return items.direction === "ascending" ? 1 : -1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    console.log(sortedUserID);

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, items: sortedUserID };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Home Page</h1>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <Link target="self" to="/">
                  View Normal
                </Link>
              </th>
              <th>Group By UserID</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                User ID
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => this.setSortedItemsUserID()}
                >
                  ⬇️
                </button>
              </th>
              <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map((item) => (
              <tr key={item.userId + item.title}>
                <td>{item.userId}</td>
                <td>{item.title}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?  I imagine you'd extract distinct `userid` values from the array, sort that extracted array, map over that sorted array, and for each element you would extract matching records from `items`, sort *that* array by `title`, and map over it to display the records.

Comment: 0. Welcome to SO, in order to get most of it and help other help you, please read:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
1. requirement when posting at SO is to SHOW what you have tried.
2. you should always make it as easy as possible to extract data from the question so instead of pictures you should use text.